Molarity into Mole Fraction
So, recently, I was solving a question wherein I had to find out an equation connecting mole fraction to molarity.
We have to express the mole fraction of the solute ($x_2$) in terms of molarity (M), molar mass of solute ($M_2$), molar mass of solvent ($M_1$) and density of solution ($\rho$, in g/L).
The equation I had to reach up to was:
$$x_2 = \frac{MM_1}{\rho + M(M_1-M_2)}$$
Here's what I tried...
Attempt #1:
$x_2 = n_2/ n_1 + n_2$  [$n_2$ and $n_1$ are moles of solute and solvent respectively]
I assumed the volume of the solution to be 1 L.
$M = n_2/V$ [moles of solute/ volume of solution in litres]
$M = n_2/ 1 L$
Moles of solution: $\rho/ (M_1 + M_2)$
[density*volume (solution)= mass of solution; mass of solution/molar mass of solution = moles of solution]
NOTE: I've denoted the molar mass of solution as $M_2+ M_1$ (molar mass of solute + molar mass of solvent).
Putting all these values:
$x_2 = \frac{M(M_1 + M_2)} {\rho}$
Attempt #2:
$x_2 = n_2/n_1 + n_2$
$M = n_2/ V$
Dividing the 2:
$x_2/M = V/n_1 + n_2$
$x_2/M = V(M_1+M_2)/V\rho$
Arrived at the same equation:
$$x_2 = \frac{M(M_1 + M_2)} {\rho}$$
Could someone please help me with how to approach this problem? What's wrong with my solution? What would be the right way to take it forward?
P.S. I'm a high school student. My understanding of Physical Chemistry is very elementary. Would appreciate a simple explanation.

Symbolically express the mass of solute from molarity, Then total mass from density. The difference is solvent mass. From that, express solvent molar amount. You already had solute molar amount from molarity. Finally, simply express the molar fraction, using molar amounts of solute and solvent.

I tried and got to the equation. Is the answer posted below the way you were suggesting? @Poutnik Thanks for the help

Molar amount of solution $\dfrac{\rho}{M_1 + M_2}$ is wrong. How did you come to it? Imagine you dissolved few grains of glucose in 1 L of water.
Would the total number of particles suddenly drop to about 1/11 of initial count? // BTW molar amount of solution is not defined, as there is not a particle of solution. You could speak about the  total molar amount of matter $n_\text{tot}=\sum_i{\dfrac{m_i}{M_i}}$

@Poutnik OK, noted. Really appreciate your time and effort in clarifying my doubt. Now I understand it.

I think your path to the final answer is wrong in some aspects of your thinking process (e.g., look Poutnik's comment). Since you have put enough effort to solve this problem yourself, I'll try to give reasonable step by step solution with correct assumptions. I'd use following symbols as you gave in the question for my answer:

Molar mass of the solvent $= M_1$; molar mass of the solute $= M_2$; and density of solution $= \rho$ (in $\pu{g L-1}$)
Mole fraction of the solvent $= n_1$; and mole fraction of the solute $= n_2$
The molarity of the solution $= \pu{M}$ (define as $\pu{mol L-1}$)
Also, I define followings as well for clarity: mass of the solvent $= m_1$; and mass of the solute $= m_2$; Thus, $m_1 = M_1n_1$ and $m_2 = M_1n_2$

Accordingly, $ \pu{M} = \dfrac{\text{moles of solute}}{\text{L of solution}} = \dfrac{n_2}{\pu{L}}\; \Rightarrow \therefore \; \pu{L} = \dfrac{n_2}{\pu{M}}$
Since by definition $\rho = \dfrac{m_1 + m_2}{\pu{L}}$, we can say $\pu{L} = \dfrac{m_1 + m_2}{\rho} = \dfrac{n_2}{\pu{M}}$. Here, we can apply defined values for $m_1$ and $m_2$ to get $n_1$ in known variables:
$$\frac{m_1 + m_2}{\rho} = \frac{n_2}{\pu{M}} = \frac{M_1n_1 + M_2n_2}{\rho}$$
$$\therefore \: n_1 = \frac{1}{M_1}\left(\frac{\rho n_2}{\pu{M}} -  M_2n_2 \right)= \frac{n_2}{M_1}\left(\frac{\rho }{\pu{M}} -  M_2 \right)$$
Now you can apply the value of $n_1$ in $ x_2 = \dfrac{n_2}{n_1 + n_2}$, to find the mole fraction $x_2$ in known variables including $n_2$, which is basically the value of $\pu{M}$. Thus, the mole fraction:
$$x_2 = \frac{\pu{M}M_1}{\rho + \pu{M}(M_1 - M_2)}$$

Also, ehm, n1, n2 are molar amounts (used correctly elsewhere), not  mole fractions. (I bet the keyboard did not write what you wanted to, having different opinion)

@Poutnik: Can't blame 100% om keyboard, because I have only one eye due to an accident! :-)

Hard to see things from more angles. :-)

Just for completeness - there are multiple equivalent ways how to reach the desired result. One is

Starting with the defining equation for the target quantity
Continuing by substitutions using intermediate quantities, going toward the given input quantities
Ending with having just given input quantities

Using symbol definitions given by the OP:
\begin{align}
x_2 &= \frac{n_2 }{ n_2 + n_1} = \frac{M \cdot V}{M \cdot V + \frac{m - m_2}{M_1}}=\frac{M \cdot V}{M \cdot V + \frac{\rho \cdot  V - M \cdot V \cdot M_2}{M_1}}=\\
&= \frac{M}{M + \frac{\rho - M \cdot M_2}{M_1}}=\frac{M \cdot M_1}{\rho + M(M_1 - M_2)}
\end{align}
As dimensional check, you can verify that
$\dfrac{M \cdot M_1}{\rho + M(M_1 - M_2)}$ is dimensionless as well as $x_2$.

$M = n_2/V$
$x_2 = \frac{n_2}{n_2 + n_1}$
Mass of solution: $M_1n_1 + M_2n_2$
Volume: $M_1n_1 + M_2n_2/ \rho$
Let moles of solution be 1, i.e., $n_1 + n_2 = 1$.
$M = \frac{x_2\rho} {M_1(1-x_2) + M_2x_2}$
$MM_1 - MM_1x_2 + MM_2x_2= x_2\rho$
$x_2(\rho + MM_1 - MM_2)= MM_1$
$$x_2 = \frac{MM_1}{\rho + M(M_1 - M_2)}$$

Let:
A = Solute
B = Solvent
$$X_A=\frac{C_A}{C}=\frac{C_A\;M}{\rho}=\frac{C_A\;\left[M_A\;X_A+M_B(1-X_A)\right]}{\rho}=\frac{C_A\;M_A\;X_A+C_A\;M_B-C_A\;M_B\;X_A}{\rho}$$
$$X_A\left(\rho+C_A\;M_B-C_A\;M_A\right)=C_A\;M_B$$
$$\boxed{X_A=\frac{M_B}{\frac{\rho}{C_A}+M_B-M_A}}$$

Molarity = Moles/L; Molefraction =Moles/Total moles
Grams of solution = 1000[density]; Grams solute = [Molarity]MW; Grams of solvent = Grams solution - grams solute.
Grams solvent/MW solvent = moles solvent
Mole fraction solute= Moles solute/total moles; MFsolvent = 1-MFsolute.
